# C# WinForms, play video using the FFmpeg library

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

According to web search results, FFmpeg.AutoGen provides video/audio frames with timing data, and I could use them to render the way I want. But I cannot find a simple example for playing a video file on a WinForms window, using FFmpeg.

[In the example file](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example/Program.cs), I can see code for initialisation and decoding video frames. How to play those frames smoothly on WinForms? Should I use some sort of DirectX library?

Comment: Looking at the code you linked, the `DecodeAllFramesToImages` is doing all the work you need. `VideoStreamDecoder()` opens the stream, `TryDecodeNextFrame()` validates the frame, then `[VideoFrameConverter].Convert()` converts the frame to a Bitmap (and resamples, eventually). Put that in a threaded Timer (or a Task with calculated Delay()) to update the UI 23~24 frames per second (you can do that and have a smooth rendering in a PictureBox, it's well tested). 25 fps and you can have stuttering (or begin to). Movies usually have fps between 23.something and 25.

Comment: Have you considered [FFME](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement)? It's for WPF, but you can use it in Windows Forms as mentioned in: [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms). [This solved issue](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement/issues/311) has sample code for  using FFME in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it right (performance wise) will take you some time i'm afraid. It's not that difficult to present a frame in a picture box for example but that wouldn't be efficient.

To use Hardware Acceleration (for decoding you can use FFmpeg's to save you from coding) but for post-processing it's all your work. To put the AVFrame in a Texture2D and present it. That's why you mention right, that you will require to use DirectX library for DirectX COM Interops. However, for C# all libraries are deprecated. I would suggest you to use SharpDX tho. It works fine for me.

As for a sample code, you can take a look at my project https://github.com/SuRGeoNix/MediaRouter which i'm planning soon to upgraded and create a custom UserControl so it will give you a "Texture2D" HW Accelerated (NV12/YUV420P) directly. I get performance equal to VLC (no CPU/RAM at all) and normal GPU usage.